# PHP regex preg_match malfunction

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am working on annotation driven ACL, specially on checking syntax and following split of given string into parameters as it is explained below. I have got a problem with PHP regex workaround.

I would like to check annotation parameters syntax using function preg_match.

Desired format of parameters :

```
foo={security module} - should pass
bar={view,delete,edit} - should pass
prelude={view, delete, edit} - should pass
typo={x} - should pass
foo={security module}prelude={view, delete, edit} - should pass
foo={security module} prelude={view, delete, edit} - should pass
```

So I have produced `^([a-z]+={{1}[a-z]+([,\s|,]{1}[a-z]+)*}\s*)+$` regex.

Expected structure of regular expression is following:

`/` - delimiter

`^` - begin of word

`[a-z]+` - parameter name (foo || bar || whatever)

`={{1}` - exactly one occurrence of ={ sequence

`[a-z]+` - at least one value of declared parameter

`[,\s|,]{1}` - exactly one occurrence of ",\s" or ","

`[a-z]+` - again parameter name (foo || bar || whatever)

`)*` - captured block of comma followed by value 0 - x times

`}` - closing bracket

`\s*` - 0 to x times occured of whitespace between individual parameters

`)+` - captured block of whole annotation parameters, because I want the annotation to have at least one parameter

When it is passed into preg_match I am still getting 0 return value (0 occurrences of pattern valid strings).

Does anyone know where I am making mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, you never need `{1}` -- if there's no quantifier after something, it always matches exactly 1 occurrence.

Comment: `[,\s|,]` doesn't mean what you say it does. It matches a single character that's either `,`, `|`, or whitespace. You're confusing it with `(,\s|,)`, which is equivalent to `,\s?` -- comma optionally followed by whitespace.

Comment: So what shouldn't pass?  Can you show examples of cases where you are not getting expected results?

Comment: Should the first line really pass? It has no comma between the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$stuff = <<< TEST
foo={security module}
bar={view,delete,edit}
prelude={view, delete, edit}
typo={x}
foo={security module}prelude={view, delete, edit}
foo={security module}prelude={view, delete, edit}
TEST;

$regex = '/(?P<name>[a-z]+)\s*=\s*\{\s*(?P<values>[a-z\s]+(?:\s*,\s*[a-z\s]+)*)\s*\}/m';
preg_match_all($regex, $stuff, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

You can remove the `\s*` if you do not want optional whitespace before and after tokens.

Comment: I have just learned to use \b boundaries of word, it helps to eliminate matches of sub-strings. So I would edit your solution to:

    (?P<name>\b[a-z]+\b)\s*=\s*\{\s*(?P<values>\b[a-z\s]+\b(?:\s*,\s*\b[a-z\s]+\b)*)\s*\}

Answer (score 0):

The following regexp works:

```
^([a-z]+={[a-z]+((?:,|\s|,\s)[a-z]+)*}\s*)+$
```

I got rid of the unnecessary `{1}` quantifiers. And I changed `[,\s|,]` to `(?:,|\s|,\s)`, which allows the parameters to be separated by either a comma (example 2), a space (example 1), or a comma followed by space (example 3).

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dO2nC7/1)

Comment: It didn't work in all cases (http://regex101.com/r/dO2nC7/4), but the most important thing is, u helped me to learn how to construct regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, you gave me a direction and helped me to finally get over this topic.

My solution:

```
\b[a-z]+\b\s*\=\s*\{\s*\b[a-z]+\b(?:(?:\s|\.)\b[a-z]+\b\s*|(?:\s*\,\s*\b[a-z]+\b\s*)*)\}\ *
```

and similar, but more strict and more readable assisted-solution:

```
\b[a-z]+\b\s*=\s*\{\b[a-z]+\b(?:(?:\ |,\ ?|\.)\b[a-z]+\b)*\}\ *
```